# = and == in Clojure

Tags: clojure

On REPL, if I define

```
(def fits (map vector (take 10 (iterate inc 0))))
```

and then call

```
(== [2] (nth fits 2))
```

I get false.

But

```
(= [2] (nth fits 2))
```

returns true.

Is this expected ? I tried (class [2]) and (class (nth fits 2) and both return Persistent Vector.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`==` is for comparing numbers. If either of its arguments is not a number, it will always return false:

```
(== :a :a)
; => false
```

As you can see by saying `(clojure.contrib.repl-utils/source ==)` at the REPL (with `repl-utils` `require`'d, of course), `==` calls the `equiv` method of `clojure.lang.Numbers`. The relevant bit of `clojure/lang/Numbers.java` (from the latest or close-to-latest commit on GitHub):

```
static public boolean equiv(Object x, Object y){
    return y instanceof Number && x instanceof Number
           && equiv((Number) x, (Number) y);
}
```

Use `=` for equality comparisons of things which may not be numbers. When you are in fact dealing with numbers, `==` ought to be somewhat faster.

Answer (score 7):

== is a type independent way of comparing numbers

```
(== 3 3.0)
;=> true

(= 3 3.0)
;=> false
```