# why clojure clojure.lang.Ratio 3/2 not＝1.5

Tags: math, clojure

I'm lost in clojure ratio. I can't understand it.  Why do the equality and inequality tests behave this way?

```
(= 3/2 1.5)
;; false
(>= 3/2 1.5)
;; true
(> 3/2 1.5)
;;false
(not= 3/2 1.5)
;; true
```

Comment: this question is not a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364566/and-in-clojure?rq=1 because the language has changed since that question was asked, so the examples in that question's established answer don't work. It also asks the question from a different context

Comment: By the way, this is not specific to ratios. `(= 1 1.0)` returns `false`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`==`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/==) for numerical comparisons where you want to know if two numbers represent the same number regardless of types:

```
user> (= 3/2 1.5)
false
user> (== 3/2 1.5)
true
```

Though keep in mind that `==` is **only for numbers** and throws if given something not a number.

```
user> (== :1 :1)
ClassCastException clojure.lang.Keyword cannot be cast to java.lang.Number  clojure.lang.Numbers.equiv (Numbers.java:206)
```

Comment: As your answer shows, `(== :1 :1)` throws an exception. It does not return false - as it used to do - or anything else.

Comment: Sorry about that, forgot to edit my answer after testing and adding the example.

Answer (score 2):

Clojure tries hard to keep you away from floats as they're susceptible to rounding errors:

```
user=> (+ 0.1 0.2)
0.30000000000000004
user=>
```

So the real reason the comparison fails is that there's no accurate way to represent 1.5 internally, **and the moment the Clojure parser consumes "1.5" information is potentially lost**.

By using  fractions, there's no loss of information, so the fraction form 3/2 can be freely passed around to other functions without fear of runaway rounding errors [as was the case with the infamous Patriot missile bug.](http://ta.twi.tudelft.nl/users/vuik/wi211/disasters.html)

Comment: Hmm.  Assuming that Clojure is using IEEE 754 binary64 floats (like Java, and pretty much every other mainstream language), `1.5` absolutely *can* be represented accurately, since it's expressible perfectly in binary as `1.1`.  `1.4` would be a different matter, of course...

Comment: okay, the correct phrasing then would be _"every time Clojure consumes a float, information could be lost..."_

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, in Clojure ratio is a type. It does not try to convert it to double or float or anything of that sort. That-way you can preserve what the number actually represents without losing any precision.

Check-out Rich Hickey's talk called "Clojure for Java Programmers" in YouTube, He explains it better.